# Changing label ggplot2 to display integers and not duplicates

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df = data.frame(n = as.integer(c(2, 1)), date = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2020-01-01")))
ggplot(df, aes(x  = date, y = n)) +
geom_line()
```

How can I (in a generic way) change the y-label so it only displays integers and not duplicates of the label? For example if I use `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma(accuracy = 1))` I will get duplicate values of `1` and `2` in the label.

Comment: What about `breaks` instead of  `labels` ?

Comment: Do you mean changing to breaks = 2? It would work, but I need a generic solution

Comment: Or `breaks=c(min:max)` so you get all integers

Comment: How about adding `breaks = round`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply tell it only to use integers as breaks and give it an arbitrarily high number to theoretically go up to:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <-  data.frame(n = as.integer(c(2, 1)), date = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2020-01-01")))

ggplot(df, aes(x  = date, y = n)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:100)
```

[image]

Or sequence along the min:max values in your dataset by 1s (I think I'd recommend this approach - can also set bottom to `0` or `1` if preferred):

```r
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$n), max(df$n), 1))
# same result
```

Or if you have every integer once as a value in the `n` variable you could have `n.breaks` set to number of rows:

```r
scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = nrow(df))
# same result, unless repetition of values or gaps in values
```

Or pass a function to `breaks` to select all unique values after rounding:

```r
scale_y_continuous(breaks = ~ unique(round(.x)))
# Again, same result only if no gaps in values
```